# Super-noob asked to build a WAN

Tags: mpls, wan

Worst case scenario here - software/sysadmin IT guy being asked to build a future proof WAN for 5-6 large sites over 50 mile radius. Must be end-to-end secure as will include personal and medical data.

Where is the best place to <s>hide</s> research my options online?
Or is my best option to bite the bullet and get a consultant in from the off?

Comment: I would recommend hiring some expertise.  It will be cheaper in the long run because you will avoid some costly mistakes.  Be sure you provide all the important information such as number of users, locations, servers, security and redundancy requirements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Personal and medical data? End-to-end secure? That probably calls for a lengthy discussions, definitions, data classification, agreements thereupon, sign-offs and paper trail that will go way beyond the WAN in itself.

In the end, for the WAN, a technical solution might emerge that isn't even extraordinarily complex as such. But the definition phase beforehand is probably pretty cumbersome. For a WAN, questions like these will arise and should be answered (not necessarily complete, this list):

- Is data path isolation required? For which classes of data?
- (How) should data be encrypted during transport? Encryption to be managed by whom?
- Are there any requirements that require firewalls at either or both ends of the isolated paths?
- Traffic/Firewall logs and audit trail for changes are of interest to whom? Retention time for the logs?
- What are the application's (ALL of them!) requirements in terms of bandwidth, latency, jitter and acceptable packet loss rates? (Don't be fooled by big megabit numbers from $WANVENDOR; consistently low latency is sometimes of much greater importance).
- Which (set of) applications are to be preferred if congestion occurs? (QoS, it's you we're looking at!)

Assuming that the sites themselves (in extenso: campuses and data centers and their networks) are up to the task (especially in, but not limited to, terms of physical security), it will still be a burden to reference all the definitions for "*beyond premises data transport*" to the given points in the documentation of processes and contracts on the given environment, provided that the latter even exist.

Therefore: I suggest to hire some expertise that should primarily help with the preparations and definitions phase. Once these things are well-defined, concise requirements for the WAN service can be drawn from there, and the implementer will have a much easier job to do, and will have goals to fulfill and to be measured against.

Depending on the legislation your environment falls into, be sure not to take this lightly - some jurisdictions have a very long an thorny whip in the context of personal and even more in medical data.